# Concatenate an array and two values into an array of unique values

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with three columns. Two of the columns (`str1` and `str2`) are nullable strings and the other is a nullable array of strings (`arr`). I need to collect all of these into a single column `arr` while removing possible duplicate values (the original array column is guaranteed not to have duplicates).

The best I've been able to do is add one string column at a time, but I'd like to know if there's a better way:

```sql
WITH foo AS (
  SELECT 'A'  AS str1, 'B'  AS str2, ['C', 'D'] AS arr UNION ALL
  -- all get concatenated
  -- ['C', 'D', 'A', 'B']
  
  SELECT 'A'  AS str1, 'B'  AS str2, ['C', 'A'] AS arr UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A'  AS str1, 'A'  AS str2, ['C', 'D'] AS arr UNION ALL
  -- 'A' is not duplicated
  -- ['C', 'A', 'B'] and ['C', 'D', 'A']

  SELECT NULL AS str1, 'B'  AS str2, ['C', 'A'] AS arr UNION ALL
  -- NULL str1 (or str2) is ignored
  -- ['C', 'A', 'B']

  SELECT 'A'  AS str1, 'B'  AS str2, NULL       AS arr UNION ALL
  -- NULL array is ignored, str1 and 2 are array_concat'ed
  -- ['A', 'B']

  SELECT NULL AS str1, NULL AS str2, NULL       AS arr
  -- handles all NULLs
  -- NULL ([] or [''] would be ok)
)
SELECT CASE WHEN str2 IS NULL
              OR str2 IN UNNEST(arr)
                 THEN arr
            WHEN arr IS NULL
                 THEN [str2]
            ELSE ARRAY_CONCAT(arr, [str2])
       END AS arr
FROM (
     SELECT CASE WHEN str1 IS NULL
                   OR str1 IN UNNEST(arr)
                      THEN arr
                 WHEN arr IS NULL
                      THEN [str1]
                 ELSE ARRAY_CONCAT(arr, [str1])
            END AS arr
          , str2
     FROM foo
)
```

In this implementation, if all the component values are `NULL`, `arr` will be `NULL`. However, an empty array or an array with a single `''` would also be acceptable in this situation. Also, the order of items in the final array is irrelevant.

So, is there a cleaner, smarter way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below query

```sql
SELECT ARRAY(SELECT DISTINCT str 
               FROM UNNEST([str1, str2] || IFNULL(arr, [])) str 
              WHERE str IS NOT NULL
       ) AS arr
  FROM foo;
```

Comment: Yep, this works! But... how does this actually work? Arrays can't have `NULL` elements, so why does this not error out when `str1` or `str2` are `NULL`? Can arrays have `NULL` within subqueries? Dark magic...

Comment: Array can be null and have nulls if you try not to store it into a final result. "BigQuery raises an error if the query result has an ARRAY which contains NULL elements, although such an ARRAY can be used inside the query."  see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#array_nulls

Answer (score 0):

Below is a little unorthodox approach, but still can be useful (at least from learning perspective)

```
select array(
    select distinct str
    from unnest(regexp_extract_all(to_json_string(t), r'"([^"]+)"')) str
    where not str in ('str1', 'str2', 'arr')
  ) arr
from foo t
```

Comment: have you tried?